# How to keep Ubuntu 11.10 and Kate editor w/terminal from changing command line when changing tabs?

Tags: c, ubuntu, tabs, ubuntu-11.10, kate

I am programming C using Kate editor in Ubuntu 11.10.  It works great, but when I change tabs in Kate, the terminal line changes to the file path of the tab I click on.

Normally this is not a big deal (other than annoyingly adding extra text to my terminal) however if I am currently RUNNNING a C program, it obviously will type at the command line, which is not so cool.

```
Example terminal window for my C program (its at a menu):

1) select opt 1
2) select opt 2

Enter choice: (here it waits for prompt from user)
```

Now when I click a tab in Kate, it wants to put in the cd / path of the file in that tab, such as:
cd /home/user/os/files

And of course since my terminal was waiting for prompt from user it gets that command.. not good.

Perhaps there is no fix, but maybe someone knows?  Obviously I could choose NOT to switch tabs or end program before switching tabs...

> Note: I probably made the mistake of putting this under StackOverflow
>   which is more of a programming area - so though repost here might be
>   best (I am not sure how to link the questions but will paste hyperlink
>   to that post - I dont want to violate any stackoverflow/superuser
>   violations)  Suggestions on merging them are welcome or if I should delete one?

[SuperUser Post](https://superuser.com/questions/481362/how-to-keep-ubuntu-11-10-and-kate-editor-w-terminal-from-changing-command-line-w)

Comment: There's a setting for that. Behavior->Synchronize terminal emulator to active document (or something like that, I'm translating it back from my native tongue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Pedro Romano at https://superuser.com/q/481362/127982:

Kate configuration under `Application > Terminal > Terminal Settings` has a **Automatically synchronise the terminal with the current document when possible** (this is on Ubuntu 12.10, so your may not have it or be slightly different).